# When doing the DC analysis of a common emitter amplifier, why can we disconnect the parts involving capacitors?

Tags: amplifier, common-emitter

[image]

I don't understand why the components involving the bypass capacitors and the coupling capacitors need to "disappear" when we are doing the DC analysis.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you give an example of the calculation you are talking about? Which components exactly are you removing? What do you mean by "voltage across the circuit"?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the DC analysis of this circuit involves disconnecting the 6K resistor after the Cout capacitor and the rest of the capacitors and I don't understand why we need to do that.

Comment: @Diana : 1. **Edit** your question to describe that. That level of detailedness is necessary for your question to be sensible! 2. DC and capacitors: You *know* how DC passes through capacitors, otherwise you wouldn't be taking a course on transistors.

Comment: Are you doing DC or AC analysis? For DC, capacitors appears as open-circuits because the cap charges up to a DC voltage and then stops passing DC current once it is charged up (that doesn't mean it won't pass AC current or currents due to changes in voltages). For AC, capacitors are that are "really large" appear as short-circuits since they are low impedance for "high" frequencies.

Comment: @DKNguyen, You are on the right track... but you need a few more steps to generalize your idea in a concept... I think I managed to do it in my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to disconnect anything just ignore them because they have infinite impedance at DC. The output resistor is ruled out of analysis when Cout becomes infinity. Disconnecting them is just a metaphor for simplifying the circuit in your mind’s eye.

Answer (score 0):

The capacitors do not affect DC voltages. They affect AC signal frequency response and amount of AC gain.

Comment: Of course they affect DC voltages. The presence of Cout makes an enormous difference in the DC voltage across the right-most 6k resistor.

Comment: At DC, the capacitor has infinite impedance and there is 0V over the 6k resistor (after capacitor is charged). So it can be considered diaconnected as it does not affect calculating the DC bias point of the circuit.

Comment: @Justme But if the capacitor was not there (replaced by a wire) then the voltage across the resistor **would not** be zero. So, the presence of Cout has a huge affect on the voltage across that resistor. My point is that the answer is incorrect as stated...capacitors **in parallel** have no affect on voltage.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Where was replacing capacitors with wire mentioned? Indeed that would make a difference, but I've only seen removing and disconnecting them being mentioned.

Comment: @Justme If you are going to make a blanket generalization that "capacitors do not affect DC voltages" then you must consider how the circuit behavior would be different with vs. without the capacitor. Obviously, if replacing a capacitor with a wire changes the DC voltages then the presence of the capacitor had some affect. The proper statement would be that "capacitors do not pass DC current".

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, You usually accuse me of trying to be original but now I have the opportunity to accuse you of the same. Although your explanation is right and can be used, this is not the case here. What you have said in your comments is if we connect a capacitor in series to an element in a circuit, we change its current and voltage... but if we connect it in parallel to an element, we do not change anything. The case here is another - the capacitors are already plugged in and charged... and we are removing them from the circuit. Then nothing changes... even if we turn them back on...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Well, it depends on what you mean by "remove them" from an operating circuit as opposed to removing them from the **design**. And I would have been much happier if this answer had started with "removing a capacitor from a circuit, under stable DC conditions, does not change the voltages or currents" but that is not what the answer said. If you or I have to make assumptions about what the writer **meant** then the writing is unclear.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, But these young people have no any experience in circuitry... they have no idea... no mental models for the behavior of these elements. If something is unclear in their questions, and we can guess what they want to say, is it better to correct it? Obviously, this is a question of fully charged capacitors, after the transient is complete. And then we do all these experiments - we remove them, put them, remove them again... and observe the currents and voltages in the circuit...

Comment: Agree to disagree. I do not agree with your sentence beginning "Obviously".

Answer (score 0):

This phenomenon belongs to the field of electrical engineering... but we meet it in the field of electronics. And because in electrical engineering courses we are not concerned with such "minor" problems, we have to explain them ourselves later in electronics courses. It turns out that we re-study electrical engineering... but only that part of it that we really need. This problem can be easily solved if electrical engineering teachers would electronics specialists (teachers). Then they would know very well what is important and what is not for the future electronics professionals.

I will not repeat the standard explanations for this phenomenon because you can find them all over the web. The role of this site is not to give what is everywhere; that is why you have asked your question here. I will use a somewhat unusual point of view to explain the phenomenon.

They say "capаcitors stop current". But how do they do that? How can we stop the current in a circuit? For simplicity's sake, let's limit ourselves to a serial circuit.

The usual way to stop the current is to break the circuit. All electric switches around us work this way and we have a very good idea of how they do it.

But in electronics there is a more sophisticated way to stop the current without breaking the circuit.  We actually do not stop the current... but ***we "stop" (neutralize) the voltage by equivalent opposing voltage***. Practically, this simply means to measure the voltage between two points of the circuit and then  connect a voltage source producing voltage with the same value but opposite polarity. As a result, the total voltage will be zero... and the current will be zero as well.

Capacitors do just that when plugged into some part of the circuit - they charge to the voltage of that part (what it would be without them) and thus cut the current through themselves; they "copy" the voltage and counteract it to the "original". When there is another element(s) connected in series (6 k resistor in your circuit diagram), they (Cout) stop the current through it as well.

Figuratively speaking, in electronic circuits ***charged capacitors act as "anti-voltage sources" neutralizing the corresponding circuit voltages***. Imagine that inside circuits there are many sources neutralized by "anti-sources". It doesn't matter if we remove or bring  them back in the circuit - nothing will change... because in the first case we stop the currents by interruption, and in the second case - by including reverse "anti-voltages".

To see the power of this idea, you can consider the interesting technique for artificially increasing the resistance in electronic circuits called with the weird name *bootstrapping*. Just type this word (and something electrical as *voltage* or *resistance*) and you will see thousands of web pages dedicated to this technique... and nowhere will you find such a simple explanation as ours... "Bootstrapping" simply means exactly the same arrangement... only instead of capacitor, we connect a following voltage "source" in series to the resistor to stop the current through it (or more officially, to "enormously increase its resistance"). We implement this "source" by transistor or op-amp voltage followers.

You can see this idea also in some circuits with negative feedback (e.g., op-amp non-inverting amplifiers), current sources, etc.

If need be, I will illustrate what I said here with some pictures. And finally, let's agree on something - all this was informal and for the purpose of a personal understanding. For all other purposes, use official explanations. It is a common practice of behavior in life when we think internally in one way and externally express ourselves in another way. This strategy allows us to save ourselves a lot of trouble...

Comment: Capacitors as "anti-voltage sources"? Good grief.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, Well, let's consider this arrangement. There is a voltage source that "wants" to pass the current through the capacitor (and a resistor in series, i.e., an RC circuit). In the beginnig, the source manages to do it. But the capacitor gradually  charges and counteracts its voltage to the input voltage (by subtracting it). Finally, it neutralizes all the input voltage... and the current is zero. What can be the name of such an opposing (counteracting) charged element? If the input voltage becomes zero, the capacitor will act instead the input voltage source... so it is a source.